# why 'grails war' generate different war file every time

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Today I found a phenomenon which made me confused.Grails is new to me.My evn just like:

```
| Grails Version: 3.3.0
| Groovy Version: 2.4.11
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_144
```

When finished coding,I executed grails command "run"and got a war package.I unzipped it and got a lot of .class files. Subsequently I executed grails command "clean" and "war", then I got another war package. I unzipped it too. I found the 2 batches of domain .class files are different from each other. I compared two domain .class files(each unzipped from one war) in intelij. Their methods' orders are different.Just like this:

[.class file compare picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0EFn.png)

You might ask why I unzipped the war package? I do this just because I don't want to deploy files that have not changed in order to save internet traffice(which of course costs).I want to send only the changed files to our server, expecting svn would ignore the .class files that have not changed.

I found the content of domain class is not changed, but the order of functions changed.Does anyone know why?Thank you.

Comment: Seems like the groovy compiler is not deterministic.  Yet your .class files are often the smaller part of a war/fatjar and you might just better off using e.g. rsync on that file, which will only need to transfer a few MB out of a few 10MB large file if you have no major changes in your third party deps.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seem that it's related to the compile-time AST transformation.